# How to get rid of keyboard layouts that I haven't installed?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

Yesterday, my keyboard started not working as I expected. Today, I figured out that I somehow switched to the Catalan keyboard and I am also able to choose between French and Albanian:

[image: Catalan]

But: the thing is, I never installed those keyboard layouts. I only use German and English.

[image: Settings]

How do I get rid of those keyboards and how do I get English back?

I am using Windows 10 Pro 22H2.

Answer (score 0):

I could install the language pack and uninstall it afterwards. That removed the unwanted items.

And for English:

1. unset as the default language
2. uninstall
3. install
4. set as the default language